# MemSQL get keys from array objects as CSV

Tags: mysql, json, csv, singlestore

I have a JSON field with value in format like below.

```
[
    {"key1": 100},
    {"key2": 101},
    {"key3": 102},
    {"key4": 103}
]
```

I want to convert to value like `key1,key1,key3,key4`

Comment: You say MemSQL in your title but then tag the question [tag:mysql]. But you also tag it [tag:singlestore], the maker of MemSQL. Which is it?

Comment: I need it for MemSQL which is renamed to singlestore now. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/singlestore/info

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the tags. Using the correct tags is important to get attention from people who follow those tags, and are the best able to answer your question.

Comment: @BillKarwin MySQL syntax mostly works for MemSQL too. Hence reply from MySQL experts will also be useful.

Comment: @IsmailS when you say "want to convert" what do you mean? You want a column in a query result, do you want to insert into another column of another table? The result in your example is it a string or ...? Is intentional that the first separator is semicolon and the rest are commas? What is the order of keys in the output?

Comment: @ivan_onys single separator. Two separator is by mistake. Corrected now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

SingleStore (formerly MemSQL) is ANSI SQL compliant and [MySQL wire protocol compatible](https://docs.singlestore.com/v7.3/guides/cluster-management/other/transitioning-from-mysql-to-memsql/), making it easy to connect with existing tools.

Depending on your JSON use case, SingleStore supports [Persisted Computed Columns](https://docs.singlestore.com/v7.3/guides/use-memsql/physical-schema-design/using-persistent-computed-columns/using-persistent-computed-columns/) for JSON blobs.

The [JSON Standard is fully supported](https://docs.singlestore.com/v7.3/guides/use-memsql/physical-schema-design/using-json/using-json/) by SingleStore.

SingleStore also supports [built-in JSON functions](https://docs.singlestore.com/v7.3/reference/sql-reference/json-functions/json-functions/) to streamline JSON blob extraction.

Comment: Thanks. So https://database.guide/json_keys-return-the-keys-from-a-json-object-in-mysql/ should work right?